# Basic tic-tac-toe JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am struggling to add the option of taking turns in this program I want to do. I need to add an `"X"` wherever the player clicks and then for the second click it will add a `"O"`. when I run this code it only does `"X"` everytime I click it. How do I change this?

```
 function X() {
     this.innerHTML = "X";
 }

 function O() {
     this.innerHTML = "O";
 }

 function XDO() {
     for (i = 1; i <= 9; i++) {
         document.getElementById("cell" + i).onclick = X;
     }
 }

 function ODO() {
     for (i = 1; i <= 9; i++) {
         document.getElementById("cell" + i).onclick = O;
     }
 }

 var turn = true;

 if (turn == true) {
     XDO();
     turn == false;

 } else if (turn == false) {
     ODO();
     turn == true;    
 }
```

Comment: `else if (turn == false) {
     ODO();
     turn == true;    
 }` does not run anytime

Comment: I would suggest to change `if (turn == true)` into `if (turn)` and `if (turn == false)` into `if (!turn)`. Not that it change the functionality of the code, but it makes just more sense (imho) to write it down like that.

Comment: You shouldn't install different handlers depending on who's turn to play. Instead, your game shall track the `currentPlayer` and whenever a cell is clicked, the `currentPlayer`'s symbol is used.

Answer (score 1):

In the below  code snippet..

```
if(turn==true)
{
XDO();
turn==false; // assignment operator should be used turn =false

}
else if(turn ==false)
{

ODO();
turn==true; // assignment operator should be used turn =true

}
```

comparison operator(==) was used, it should have been assignment operator (=)